# Apt fails with "The repository does not have a Release File"

Tags: apt, vpn, pop-os, ppa

I recently tried installing surfshark-vpn and openvpn3 using the following guides.

https://surfshark.com/blog/how-to-set-up-a-vpn-on-linux

https://openvpn.net/cloud-docs/openvpn-3-client-for-linux/ (I feel like something in this guide might be the problem)

But since then, `apt` and `apt-get` fail giving the following message:

```
Hit:1 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary groovy InRelease
Ign:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                   
Ign:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease                
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Ign:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease
Ign:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease
Err:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I've tried searching on how I can fix this but everything I've found doesn't seem to help. The most common answers seem to be:

- Run `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:something here` But I don't what what to put after `ppa:`
- Run `ppa-purge` but I don't have that program and I can't install it since apt and apt-get don't work.
- Delete a line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` but it looks like everything in that file is already commented out. (Will show it's contents below)

Does anyone have any suggestions for me? I'm considering just backing up my files and reinstalling but I'd much rather prefer to learn how to fix this.

I am currently using Pop!OS v20.10

This is my `sources.list` file

```
## See sources.list(5) for more information, especialy
# Remember that you can only use http, ftp or file URIs
# CDROMs are managed through the apt-cdrom tool.

# deb cdrom:[Pop_OS 20.10 _Groovy Gorilla_ - Release amd64 (20210225)]/ groovy main restricted
# deb cdrom:[Pop_OS 20.10 _Groovy Gorilla_ - Release amd64 (20210225)]/ stable main restricted
# deb cdrom:[Pop_OS 20.10 _Groovy Gorilla_ - Release amd64 (20210225)]/ unstable main restricted
```

Thanks

Comment: https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/ might have to do with this.

Comment: Try to use another Ubuntu repository mirror.

Comment: Groovy hat reached EOL thus the server are down

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with pop-os. Meaning I have no idea where exactly the ubuntu repositories are selected, but I think from /etc/apt/sources.list like ubuntu.
[ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/)

the sources from code `#EOL upgrade sources.list` you can use also to install the software. For groovy

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ groovy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ groovy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ groovy-security main restricted universe multiverse
# Optional
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ groovy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: This will work. But using an LTS release is more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Groovy is EOL, Pop _os sources.list accept `bionic`, `focal`, `hirsute` and `impish` codenames. You can fetch the remote dir through curl:

```
 curl -sSL http://apt.pop-os.org/release/dists/ |awk -F'"' 'FNR >3 {print $2}'
```

sample output:

```
../
bionic/
focal/
hirsute/
impish/
```

Pop_os 20.04 is the LTS release,it is recommended for you.

Comment: I think without apt-pinning magic It will not work , to turn back to 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't `apt` and `apt-get` that are failing. The error messages are due to `apt update` and/or `apt-get update`. You should still be able to install `ppa-purge` with `apt install ppa-purge`.

> Delete a line in /etc/apt/sources.list but it looks like everything in that file is already commented out. (Will show it's contents below)

Go to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. This directory contains the repositories you have manually added which seem to be causing the issue during updates. Comment out unnecessary lines from the problem-causing files or delete the entire files.